# Explanation on why certain nodes show up

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

All-
Very new to XSLT. I could use some help to understand some basic.

the xml

```
    <root>
       <Article>
          <Bullettext>10,00 </Bullettext>
          <Bullettext>8,00 </Bullettext>

       </Article>
       <Article>
          <something>some text</something>
       </Article>
       <Article>
          <Corpsdetexte>Bulgaria</Corpsdetexte>

          <Bullettext>15,0 </Bullettext>
          <Bullettext>10,0 </Bullettext>

       </Article>
       <Article>
          <Corpsdetexte>Somaialia</Corpsdetexte>
          <bunk>Test</bunk>

             <Bullettext>15,1</Bullettext>
             <Bullettext>10,2</Bullettext>
             <Bullettext>20,3</Bullettext>
             <Bullettext>25,4</Bullettext>
             <Bullettext>30,5 </Bullettext>

       </Article>
    </root>
```

## XSLT 1

```
<xsl:stylesheet
version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>



    <!-- copy all elements as is -->

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- process only the first bullet text  element under this template -->
    <xsl:template match="Bullettext[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='Bullettext'])]">
        <!-- find the element that we want to stop at -->
        <xsl:variable name="stop" select="./following-sibling::*[name() != 'Bullettext'][1]"/>
        <LIST>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- first, the simple case:  there's no element we have to stop at -->
                <xsl:when test="not($stop)">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="item"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::Bullettext" mode="item"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- is this required -->
                <!-- transform all elements between the start and stop index into items -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="start_index" select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="stop_index" select="count($stop/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[position() &gt;= $start_index 
and position() &lt;= $stop_index]"
mode="item"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </LIST>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Bullettext" />


    <xsl:template match="Bullettext" mode="item">
        <ITEM>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </ITEM>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 2 _ Notice the missing 'otherwise in the choose.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>



    <!-- copy all elements as is -->


    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- process only the first bullet text  element under this template -->
    <xsl:template match="Bullettext[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='Bullettext'])]">
        <!-- find the element that we want to stop at -->
        <xsl:variable name="stop" select="./following-sibling::*[name() != 'Bullettext'][1]"/>
        <LIST>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- first, the simple case:  there's no element we have to stop at -->
                <xsl:when test="not($stop)">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="item"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::Bullettext" mode="item"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- is this required -->
                <!-- transform all elements between the start and stop index into items -->
            </xsl:choose>
        </LIST>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Bullettext" />


    <xsl:template match="Bullettext" mode="item">
        <ITEM>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </ITEM>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both give the same result

```
<root>
    <Article>
        <LIST>
            <ITEM>10,00 </ITEM>
            <ITEM>8,00 </ITEM>
        </LIST>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <something>some text</something>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <Corpsdetexte>Bulgaria</Corpsdetexte>
        <LIST>
            <ITEM>15,0 </ITEM>
            <ITEM>10,0 </ITEM>
        </LIST>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <Corpsdetexte>Somaialia</Corpsdetexte>
        <bunk>Test</bunk>
        <LIST>
            <ITEM>15,1 </ITEM>
            <ITEM>10,2 </ITEM>
            <ITEM>20,3 </ITEM>
            <ITEM>25,4 </ITEM>
            <ITEM>30,5 </ITEM>
        </LIST>
    </Article>
</root>
```

What is the value of otherwise in the example. And why does it work without otherwise?

Note: this was an answer to question posed. Sorry do not have a link

Comment: What's the difference between the input and the output?

Comment: @Mathias - My carelessness. Sorry! I updated the source xml. The objective is to  wrap the Bullettext nodes around list node and changing the node name from Bullettext to item

Comment: @Mathias - looks like the out will be different after all. Any help understand the flow for first xslt will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input does not contain any `Bullettext` nodes. Therefore, the three templates matching `Bullettext` are never applied and it makes no difference what they contain.

However, with an input such as:

```
<root>
    <Article>
        <Bullettext>alpha</Bullettext>
        <Bullettext>bravo</Bullettext>
        <text>charlie</text>
        <Bullettext>delta</Bullettext>
    </Article>
</root>
```

you will see a difference: the first XSLT will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Article>
      <LIST>
         <ITEM>alpha</ITEM>
         <ITEM>bravo</ITEM>
      </LIST>
      <text>charlie</text>
      <LIST>
         <ITEM>delta</ITEM>
      </LIST>
   </Article>
</root>
```

while the second one will produce only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Article>
      <LIST/>
      <text>charlie</text>
      <LIST>
         <ITEM>delta</ITEM>
      </LIST>
   </Article>
</root>
```

Comment: @micahel hor257k Yes, you are right, I updated the source xml. I am sure I am getting between the outputs.  can you explain what is happening in the first XSLT. And when the 'when' part is executing and when otherwise. I am struggling to understand this.

Comment: @StillStumbling You need an example where `Bullettext` nodes are interspersed with other nodes as siblings. What you have is an example of "sibling recursion", an alternate form of grouping if you will.